# MySQL SUM IF column has specific value

Tags: mysql, sum

Is there a way to sum rows only when they meet certain condition?, If they dont they must be copied to the new table. For example, if i have this table

```
| id | A | B |
--------------
|  1 | a | 2 |
|  1 | b | 4 |
|  1 | c | 1 |
|  2 | a | 4 |
|  3 | a | 1 |
|  3 | b | 5 |
```

I want an output like this

```
| id |  A  | B |
--------------
|  1 | a,b | 6 |
|  1 |  c  | 1 |
|  2 |  a  | 4 |
|  3 | a,b | 6 |
```

It will only sum if column 'A' is 'a' or 'b', it will just copy the value if its 'c'

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can do this in two different Select queries. In first Select query, just consider the cases where `A` has either values 'a' or 'b'. In the second Select query, consider the rest of the values (`A NOT IN ('a','b')`)
- Use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine the results into a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Order the Derived table result-set in ascending order by `id`.
- We use aggregation functions like [`Group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to get comma separated string (for a and b), and sum of the `B` values, respectively.

Try the following:

```
SELECT dt.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT A) AS A,
         SUM(B) AS B
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE A IN ('a','b') 
  GROUP BY id

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT id, 
         A,
         B
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE A NOT IN ('a', 'b')
  GROUP BY id, A, B
) AS dt 

ORDER BY dt.id ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, this wokrs. But what would happen if i need to excecute a subquery to get the first table (the one i need to sum the values). It will not be to "heavy" or take a lot of time if i excecute the subquery twice?

Comment: @LuisGarcia queries wont be "heavy" if tables are properly indexed.

Comment: @LuisGarcia happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not show all possible cases.

But I think that probably you don't need to overcomplicate solution with `UNION`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d473d3/6

```
SELECT id, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(A), 
   SUM(B)
FROM abc
GROUP BY CONCAT(id, IF(A IN ('a','b'),'$',A))
```